# How can I pass value to a method which doesnt have parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method

```
  public User authenticateUser(){
      Scanner scr = new Scannery(System.in);
      String name = scr.nextLine();
      String password = scr.nextLine();
      return new User(name,passworrd);
    }
```

and I wonder if I can unit-test it if it actually creates the user. However it doesnt have parameters.

I tried the following:

```
@Test
public void testIfReadCredentialsReturnUser(){
    User user = mock(User.class);
    ConsoleView view = new ConsoleView();
    view.readCredentials().setEmail("asd.com");
    view.readCredentials().setPassword("asd");
    assertNotNull(view.readCredentials());
}
```

This however actually makes me pass the arguements with scanner, what I cant do under testing obviously.
Other logics were tried aswell. I also tried using `when()`, `thenReturn()`, `thenAnswer()`, but I couldn't find a way to solve this, as I'm fairly new to mocking.

Can somebody share some ideas with me please?

Comment: Can you change the method signatures?  You need to decouple of the authenticate from the data input.

Comment: Sadly no, as this code is a part of an exercise where I had to implement the method like this.

Comment: OK, I posted a solution.  But I must say that if you ever encounter such code as is in your exercise in a professional environment, I would expect rapid termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is what you can do:

```
String data = "TestName\nTestPW\n";
InputStream testInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes() );
InputStream old = System.in;
System.setIn(testInput);
user = authenticateUser();
System.setIn(old);
```